# How to make a website that allows sign in using a valid email id and password

Tags: php, jquery, html, joomla

I am wondering wether i cam make a website which has a join member button. So if the user presses that button it will take to a new page where user can sign in with with their email id and pass. **[remember there is no option for create a new account]** Only i have is sign in using you current email Id and password. or Facebook authentication or twitter authentication.

Is it possible to make so. i need to validate for cases like if user going a wrong email id and password, or wrong Facebook email id and password same for twitter.

Only the user should be able to login using their email address and password. Is it possible to make like that. Please let me now!! Any hits.. Helps every thing is appreciated!!!

Comment: **Age old question:** So what have you tried?

Comment: yes you can do this, check this https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib

Comment: @obiNullPoiиteяkenobi will i able to get the password and email id to my mail.. is that possible.......

Comment: you want to get password and email id of facebook/twitter users ? it sounds fishy and i can say do not do that otherwise your website will get banned .. in other words it called phishing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very broad.  To answer it in a broad way, yes: it is possible.

I would recommend looking in to [WordPress.org](http://www.wordpress.org).  You will have user authentication built-in.  There are a host of plugins that would enable Twitter and Facebook login.  [Here's on example](https://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-and-twitter-login/).  I haven't tried that one, and you can find many more by searching Google for "Facebook Login Wordpress".

Comment: will i able to get the password and email id to my mail.. is that possible

Comment: I don't fully understand your question.  As the administrator who sets up the website, you would have complete control over the users with WordPress.  You can add and delete them at will, and you can enable or disable the ability to "self-register".